How to disable vscode from auto generating .vscode/settings.json with "nuxt.isNuxtApp:false"
About a year ago, I was learning Nuxt, so I installed some Nuxt related extensions in vscode.
Then I found everytime I open a project in vscode, it auto generates .vscode/settings.json in the root directory, and the content is always the same:
{
    "nuxt.isNuxtApp": false
}

Now I uninstalled all the Nuxt related extensions (maybe some extensions hide somewhere, I don't know), the problem is still there.
I opened the the Settings page in vscode, searched nuxt, tried to turn on and turn off the Is Nuxt App option like the image below, but the problem is still there.

What can I do to resolve this problem ?

I had the same problem but was able to solve it.
I uninstalled the extensions too but I found that the files remained in the extensions directory.
So I removed the files and restart VS Code.
Mac:
ls ~/.vscode/extensions | grep nuxt | xargs rm -rf

